# Rails print navigation bar using loop and highlight button leading to current page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I'm newbie on rails.

I would like to create nav bar like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) on top of page. "CSS" button is highlighted, because it leads to current page.

I would like to store paths and button titles in some place. Arrays would be ok I guess?

For example:

```
paths = ['root_path', 'articles_path']
titles = ['Home', 'Articles list']
```

Using those two arrays I would be able to print nav bar using one loop. I could easily remove or add items to it. Also I could include condition inside loop, so button leading to current page would have some html class attached (Changing it's background).

Where should I put those arrays?
Is there better/more intelligent way to achieve same thing?

P.S. I don't want to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use hash.

Declare a ruby hash with a name say "nav_bars"

```
@nav_bars = { "Home": "root_path", "Articles_list": "articles_path" }
```

Then you can loop over the hash in your views as

```
<% @nav_bars.each do |key, value|%>
    <h3> <%= link_to key, value %> </h3
<% end%>
```

Comment: What file should I put that hash in?

Comment: you can put it in your controller as an instance variable

Comment: Could u also tell me how to make that variable accesable in my view? I can't figure it out.

Comment: for eg:
class HomeController < ApplicationController
     def index
          @nav_bars = { "Home": "root_path", "Articles_list": "articles_path" }  
     end
end

in your view  home/index.html.erb
you can use this instance variable